# Matplotlib 3D scatter color lost after redraw

Tags: python, matplotlib

Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891994/matplotlib-3d-scatter-plot-with-color-gradient), I want a 3D scatter plot with prescribed colors for each point. The example posted in the question works on my system, but after the first redraw (for instance after saving or if I rotate the image) the color seems to be lost, i.e. all the points are drawn in blue color with the usual depth information. Please see the modified example below.

My system is Python 2.6.7 with matplotlib 1.1.0 installed from macports on a mac 10.8.0. I use the MacOSX backend.

Does anyone know how to circumvent this problem?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

# Create Map
cm = plt.get_cmap("RdYlGn")

x = np.random.rand(30)
y = np.random.rand(30)
z = np.random.rand(30)

col = np.arange(30)

fig = plt.figure()
ax3D = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax3D.scatter(x, y, z, s=30, c=col, marker='o', cmap=cm)

plt.savefig('image1.png')
plt.savefig('image2.png')
```

Here are the two images, I get:
[image: First image]
[image: Second image]

Comment: Hm, same on windows. If I comment out the line `col = np.arange(30)
`, both plots come out identical. Can't explain why though. `pyplot` is a stateful module, and I don't think it is wise to open a new figure without closing the old one. If keep only one figure open at all times, I think such effects could be prevented.

Comment: I just noticed that the code actually uses two figures. This was not the cause of the problem, though. I removed the first figure from the example code and the problem persists. Thanks for pointing out that the problem also exists on windows. It seems to me that this is some kind of bug.

Comment: Just as a note for future visitors, this appears to be fixed in MatPlotLib 1.2.0 :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not clear why this is happening, and it certainly is a bug. Here I provide a hack to get the result you want, though it is not *as* automatic as one would want.

For some reason, the `Patch3DCollection` representing the scatter points is not updated after the first rendering. This update is essential, because it is where unique colors are set for each collection patch.  To force it to reinitialize, you can use the `changed` method on the `Patch3DCollection` (really a `ScalarMappable` method), and this just documents that a change *happend*. When the figure is drawn, it checks if an update happened, and then it redefines the colors. If it didn't, this process is skipped.

To force this update to occur automatically, one would like to do this on every 'draw' event. To do this, one must [register a method](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/event_handling.html) using the `canvas`'s `mpl_connect` method (see linked tutorial).

This example shows how saving the figure twice preserves the color mapping, but if you uncomment the `plt.show()` line, it will still work (on rotation for example).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

# Create Map
cm = plt.get_cmap("RdYlGn")

# added a seed so consistant plotting of points
np.random.seed(101)
x = np.random.rand(30)
y = np.random.rand(30)
z = np.random.rand(30)

col = np.arange(30)

fig = plt.figure()
#ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
#scatCollection = ax.scatter(x,y,
ax3D = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
# keep track of the Patch3DCollection:
scatCollection = ax3D.scatter(x, y, z, s=30, 
                            c=col, 
                            marker='o',
                            cmap=cm
                            )
def forceUpdate(event):
    global scatCollection
    scatCollection.changed()

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('draw_event',forceUpdate)

#plt.show()

plt.savefig('image1.png')

plt.savefig('image2.png')
```

Ideally it should not be required to do this, and the global `scatCollection` should be accessed using other methods (I'm working on doing this). But this works for now...