# Saving scatterplot animations with matplotlib produces blank video file

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, ffmpeg, scatter

I am having a very similar problem to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14739969/saving-scatterplot-animations-with-matplotlib)

but the suggested solution doesn't work for me.

I have set up an animated scatter plot using the matplotlib animation module. This works fine when it is displaying live. I would like to save it to an avi file or something similar. The code I have written to do this does not error out but the video it produces just shows a blank set of axes or a black screen. I've done several checks and the data is being run and figure updated it's just not getting saved to video...

I tried removing "animated=True" and "blit=True" as suggested in  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14739969/saving-scatterplot-animations-with-matplotlib)  but that did not fix the problem.

I have placed the relevant code below but can provide more if necessary. Could anyone suggest what I should do to get this working?

```
def initAnimation(self):
        rs, cfgs = next(self.jumpingDataStreamIterator)     
        #self.scat = self.axAnimation.scatter(rs[0], rs[1], c=cfgs[0], marker='o')
        self.scat = self.axAnimation.scatter(rs[0], rs[1], c=cfgs[0], marker='o', animated=True)
        return self.scat,


def updateAnimation(self, i):
    """Update the scatter plot."""
    rs, cfgs = next(self.jumpingDataStreamIterator)
    # Set x and y data...
    self.scat.set_offsets(rs[:2,].transpose()) 
    #self.scat = self.axAnimation.scatter(rs[0], rs[1], c=cfgs[0], animated=True)
    # Set sizes...
    #self.scat._sizes = 300 * abs(data[2])**1.5 + 100
    # Set colors..
    #self.scat.set_array(cfgs[0])
    # We need to return the updated artist for FuncAnimation to draw..
    # Note that it expects a sequence of artists, thus the trailing comma.
    matplotlib.pyplot.draw()
    return self.scat,

def animate2d(self, steps=None, showEvery=50, size = 25):
    self.figAnimation, self.axAnimation = matplotlib.pyplot.subplots()
    self.axAnimation.set_aspect("equal")
    self.axAnimation.axis([-size, size, -size, size])
    self.jumpingDataStreamIterator = self.jumpingDataStream(showEvery)

    self.univeseAnimation = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(self.figAnimation, 
                            self.updateAnimation, init_func=self.initAnimation,
                            blit=True)
    matplotlib.pyplot.show()

def animate2dVideo(self,fileName=None, steps=10000, showEvery=50, size=25):
    self.figAnimation, self.axAnimation = matplotlib.pyplot.subplots()
    self.axAnimation.set_aspect("equal")
    self.axAnimation.axis([-size, size, -size, size])
    self.Writer = matplotlib.animation.writers['ffmpeg']
    self.writer = self.Writer(fps=1, metadata=dict(artist='Universe Simulation'))
    self.jumpingDataStreamIterator = self.jumpingDataStream(showEvery)

    self.universeAnimation = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(self.figAnimation, 
                            self.updateAnimation, scipy.arange(1, 25), init_func=self.initAnimation)

    self.universeAnimation.save('C:/universeAnimation.mp4', writer = self.writer)
```

Comment: Could you reduce this down to a the minimal amount of code you need to reproduce the issue?  This is clearly part of a larger class, and it is not clear that this is functional as stand alone code. Please help us to help you.

Comment: does the _exact_ code in http://stackoverflow.com/a/14740703/380231 work or not work if you run it on your system?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I have found a work around by simply saving lots of individual images and then calling ffmpeg to chain them together. This isn't ideal but gets the job done.

When I run the code here http://stackoverflow.com/a/14740703/380231 I get the following error:

....
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 2093, in print_figure
    **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 483, in print_raw
    renderer._renderer.write_rgba(filename_or_obj)
RuntimeError: Error writing to file

Comment: Please post your last comment as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the delay. I have found a work around by simply saving lots of individual images and then calling ffmpeg to chain them together. This isn't ideal but gets the job done. (part of larger class)

```
def easyway(self, frames):
    ##INSERT CODE TO GET xdata and ydata!
    for i in range(0, frames):
       fileName = "videoName"+"%04d.png" % i
       matplotlib.pyplot.scatter(xdata,ydata,c=coldata, marker='*',
                              s=15.0, edgecolor='none')
       matplotlib.pyplot.savefig(self.workingDirectory+'temp/'+fileName, dpi=dpi)
       matplotlib.pyplot.close()   
       ##INSERT CODE TO UPDATE xdata and ydata!
    self.createVideoFile(fps)#calls FFMpeg to chain together all the pictures

    if cleanUp:#removes all the picture files created in the process
        print "temporary picture files being removed..."
        self.clearDirectory()
    print "FINISHED"

def clearDirectory(self,directoryName='temp'):
    files = glob.glob(self.workingDirectory+directoryName+"/*")
    for f in files:
        os.remove(f)

def createVideoFile(self,fps=3):
    command="ffmpeg -f image2 -r %s -i %s%s" % (str(fps), self.workingDirectory+'temp/', self.universe.description)
    command+="%04d.png"
    command+=" -c:v libx264 -r 30 %s.mp4" % (self.workingDirectory+'videos/'+self.universe.description)
    print "Running command:"
    print command
    p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    output = p.communicate()[0]
    print "output\n"+"*"*10+"\n"
    print output
    print "*"*10
    print "Video file has been written"
```