# Saving matplotlib.animation outputs a 0 second video

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, ffmpeg

I am fairly new to matplotlib and animations, the animation I have works when using `pyplot.show` but when attempting to use the `animation.save` function, the only thing outputted is a 0 second video with the initial frame of the animation.

This is my code:

```
plt.rcParams['animation.ffmpeg_path'] = r'C:\FFMPEG\bin\ffmpeg.exe'
FFwriter = animation.FFMpegWriter()     
video_ani.save('basic_animation1.mp4', writer = FFwriter, fps=30, extra_args=['-vcodec', 'libx264'])
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to supply the arguments to the FFMpegWriter class, not to `animate.save`. The documenation says:

> fps, codec, bitrate, extra_args, metadata are used to construct a MovieWriter instance and can only be passed if writer is a string.

So you could try

```
FFwriter = animation.FFMpegWriter(fps=30, codec="libx264")     
video_ani.save('basic_animation1.mp4', writer = FFwriter )
```

where the codec is specified using the `codec` argument instead of some extra argument.

Appart from that you'd probably need to test certain things:

- Can you save the animation as animated gif?

  - If yes, then you have a problem creating the mp4,
  - if no, you may have a problem with the animation itself.
- What does using another codec specification do? I always used `codec="h264"`, maybe that matters.