# I generated an animation using matplotlib and a for loop, how can I save this animation (as an mp4 file, for instance)?

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib, animation

I have an animation that was generated using this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation
import numpy as np
from IPython.display import display, clear_output

t = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi)
x = np.sin(t)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
l, = ax.plot([0,2*np.pi],[-1,1])

animate = lambda i: l.set_data(t[:i], x[:i])

for i in range(len(x)):
    animate(i)
    clear_output(wait=True)
    display(fig)
    
plt.show()
```

and it displays the animation very nicely in matplotlib by plotting, clearing, and plotting the next frame. How can I modify this code so that the output is instead an mp4?

Comment: You will need to have an [MovieWriter like ffmpeg installed](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.Animation.html?highlight=anim%20save#matplotlib.animation.Animation.save).

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42258439/saving-matplotlib-animation-outputs-a-0-second-video

Comment: See also the [celluloid library](https://pypi.org/project/celluloid/) which offers a simple way to create and save animations.