# Pyplot colorbar not consistent when animating colormesh

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-animation

I have tried various methods of animating a colormesh plot. I believe that FuncAnimation is the simplest way for me to animate my colormesh. The code I have written is shown below

```
r = np.linspace(0,R,Nr)
z = np.linspace(0,H,Nz)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

cax = ax.pcolormesh(R, Z, T[0,:,:], cmap='RdBu_r', vmin=0, vmax=200)
ax.set_title("Variation of temperature with space" )
ax.set_xlabel("r (m)")
ax.set_ylabel("z (m)")
fig.colorbar(cax)

def update(i):
    cax = set_array(T[i,:,:])
    ax.set_title("Variation of temperature with space after a time of " + str(i*dt_real) + " seconds" )
    return cax
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,update,interval = 100, frames=len(T)-1)
ani.save('123.gif')
plt.show()
```

In my data r and z are arrays representing dimensions. T is a 3d matrix. Index 1 is time, 2 is z, and 3 is r. I want to animate the colormesh of T for each time step t.

I have had no problems generating a single colormesh. When I animate the colormesh, the gif generated does not replicate the series of colormeshes if I generated them one by 1. The colorbar appears to flicker between frames and is constantly changing throughout the animation. I have looked online and can find no other example of this occuring. My code almost directly replicates other versions which do not face the same problem ([See example here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-animate-a-pcolormesh-in-matplotlib))

[Gif generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLLrG.gif). Note flickering on the colorbar

**Solution:**

Flickering and variation disappeared when creating an mp4 file as opposed to gif.

Comment: The gif format can only save 255 different colors. Maybe you could try to save to [mp4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37146420/saving-matplotlib-animation-as-mp4)? Also, gifs 255 colors are "decided" on the first frame (by some kind of color majority vote, where grey values are used to get nice text). If that frame doesn't contain a lot of the middle colors, they get less attention.  You could try to first to mp4, and converting it afterward to gif (via VLC, of ffmpeg).

Comment: @JohanC Thank you.  The problem is resolved when I use an mp4 instead of gif. For my own understanding, do you know why this works? All I have changed is the file format so how does converting to a gif change the actual frames, whereas mp4 does not. I did not know that gif only had 255 colors, but I would have thought this would only affect the range of colors on each frame, not the frames themself. Thanks again!

Comment: Well, 255 is for the full animation. It's a very old format, when 256 colors seemed like the maximum one could ever display on a graphics card. For most animations, it uses more memory than an MP4.