# Matplotlib colormap in scatter plot: AttributeError: Unknown property size

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I want to plot a set of 3D coordinates in a scatter plot and add information from another array of the same size (h_m), using a colorbar. 
I've followed the example in question [Python 3d scatterplot colormap issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15053575/python-3d-scatterplot-colormap-issue):

```
cmhot = plt.get_cmap("hot")
ax.scatter(x, y, z, marker='o', size=10, c=h_m, cmap=cmhot)
```

I get  AttributeError: Unknown property size

Comment: It should be `s=10` and not `size=10`

Comment: `size` does not seem to be a valid keyword

Comment: @Alessandra Ferri: If my answer worked, could it be accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can see in the matplotlib documentation of `scatter` [**HERE IN THIS WEBSITE**](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter)
 you will find that you give your input in `scatter` by the keyword `s` **and not by `size`**.

If you change it to `s=10` it will work!

To see more about how the `size` parameter works, please refer to this [**PREVIOUS ANSWER POSTED IN STACKOVERFLOW**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14827650/pyplot-scatter-plot-marker-size)