# matplotlib 3D plot color coding by value range

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to produce a 3D plot with two colors. One color for values above zero and another color for values below zero. I just cannot figure out how to implement this in the code.

Here is my current code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.tri as mtri
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('...temp\\3ddata.csv', sep = ',', index_col  = False)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

x = df['P']
y = df['T']
z = df['S']

ax.plot(x, y, zs= 0, zdir = 'z', c= 'r')

ax.scatter(x,y, z, c = 'b', s = 20)

ax.set_xlabel('Pressure (Bar)')
ax.set_zlabel('Residual subcooling (J*Kg-1*K-1')
ax.set_ylabel('Temperaure of LNG (K)')

plt.show()
```

[image: 3DPLOT]

I've read a few examples but couldn't apply them to my data. Is it possible to do this with a for loop?

or something along the lines of:

```
use_c = {<=0: "red", >=0 "blue"}

#ax.plot(x, y, zs= 0, zdir = 'z', c= 'r')

ax.scatter(x,y, z, c = [use_c[x[0]] for x in z], s = 20)
```

Something that links the value of z to a color.

Comment: You could try using the seismic colormap http://matplotlib.org/users/colormaps.html

Comment: What value, y or z ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have figured it out alas.

I needed to specify a variable for c then reference this in the ax.scatter(*kwargs):

c = (z<=0)

ax.scatter(x,y,z, c = c, cmap = 'coolwarm', size = 30)

this gives me a nice plot as follows: [image]

Answer (score 4):

if you pass to `scatter` a boolean array as the value of the optional argument `c`,
you have your points in two colors from the extremes of the current colormap

```
ax.scatter(x,y, z, c = z<0, s = 20)
```

You may want to set the edge width to zero, otherwise all the dots look almost black.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some example code which shows how to apply color map with a scatter plot.

```
import matplotlib.cm as cm
plt.scatter(x, y, c=t, cmap=cm.colormap_name)
```

Where t is some value you want to set the color based on.

You can find a full list of colormaps here:

http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html

Taken from:

[Scatter plot and Color mapping in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17682216/scatter-plot-and-color-mapping-in-python)

Comment: Unfortunately these are for 2D scatter plots.

Comment: Sorry about that, I presumed it works in same way. Seems it's a bit more tricky. Have you seen this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15053575/python-3d-scatterplot-colormap-issue