# Matplotlib 3d scatterplot missing colour map

Tags: python, matplotlib, color-mapping

I posted earlier about a program I was attempting to make to plot four-dimensional data (xyz coords and voltages) on a 3d scatter plot with a colour map dependent upon the magnitude of the voltages.

I'm able to run my program without error (suggesting I'm not missing any packages) though my datapoints are always coming up as being blue, indicating that the colour map is not being applied properly. Can anybody see what the problem is? I'm most appreciative if so.

```
from pylab import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

x = array([-4,-4,   -4,-4,-4,-4,-4,-4,-4,-4,-4,-4,-4,-4,-4,-4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,  0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,    4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, 2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  -5, -4.5,   -4, -3.5,   -3, -2.5,   -2, -1.5,   -1, -0.5,   0,  0.5,    1,  1.5,    2,  2.5,    3,  3.5,    4,  4.5,    5,  5.5,    6,  6.5,    -6.5,   -6, -5.5,
    ])
y = array([-0.1,    3.95,   5.8,4.4,0.1,-4,-5.8,-4,1,2.4,3.2,   1.6,-0.8,-2.6,-3.3,-1.4,-0.1,3.95,  5.8,4.4,0.1,-4,-5.8,-4,1,2.4,   3.2,    1.6,    -0.8,   -2.6,   -3.3,   -1.4,   -0.1,   3.95,   5.8,    4.4,    0.1,    -4, -5.8,   -4, 1,  2.4,    3.2,    1.6,    -0.8,   -2.6,   -3.3,   -1.4,   -0.1,   3.95,   5.8,    4.4,    0.1,    -4, -5.8,   -4, 1,  2.4,    3.2,    1.6,    -0.8,   -2.6,   -3.3,   -1.4,   -0.1,   3.95,   5.8,    4.4,    0.1,    -4, -5.8,   -4, 1,  2.4,    3.2,    1.6,    -0.8,   -2.6,   -3.3,   -1.4,   0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
    ])
z = array([5.85,    4, 0.2,-3.8,-5.85,-4.1,-0.15,4,2.75,1.4,-0.3,   -2.6,   -2.75,-2.7, 1.2,    3.2,5.85,4, 0.2,-3.8,-5.85,-4.1,-0.15,  4,  2.75,   1.4,    -0.3,   -2.6,   -2.75,  -2.7,   1.2,    3.2,    5.85,   4,  0.2,    -3.8,   -5.85,  -4.1,   -0.15,  4,  2.75,   1.4,    -0.3,   -2.6,   -2.75,  -2.7,   1.2,    3.2,    5.85,   4,  0.2,    -3.8,   -5.85,  -4.1,   -0.15,  4,  2.75,   1.4,    -0.3,   -2.6,   -2.75,  -2.7,   1.2,    3.2,    5.85,   4,  0.2,    -3.8,   -5.85,  -4.1,   -0.15,  4,  2.75,   1.4,    -0.3,   -2.6,   -2.75,  -2.7,   1.2,    3.2,    0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
    ])
v = array([0.29,    0.32,   0.3,    0.27,   0.3,    0.28,   0.31,   0.28,   0.19,   0.18,   0.19,   0.18,   0.19,   0.19,   0.2,    0.19,   0.12,   0.12,   0.11,   0.1,    0.11,   0.15,   0.14,   0.13,   0.18,   0.18,   0.18,   0.18,   0.18,   0.18,   0.18,   0.18,   0.32,   0.31,   0.3,    0.31,   0.29,   0.3,    0.32,   0.31,   0.2,    0.21,   0.19,   0.19,   0.19,   0.19,   0.19,   0.2,    0.13,   0.12,   0.14,   0.14,   0.17,   0.17,   0.16,   0.14,   0.18,   0.18,   0.18,   0.19,   0.19,   0.19,   0.19,   0.18,   0.16,   0.18,   0.2,    0.19,   0.18,   0.15,   0.16,   0.18,   0.18,   0.18,   0.18,   0.17,   0.17,   0.17,   0.18,   0.18,   0.13,   0.14,   0.15,   0.16,   0.17,   0.17,   0.18,   0.18,   0.18,   0.18,   0.18,   0.18,   0.18,   0.18,   0.18,   0.17,   0.17,   0.16,   0.15,   0.14,   0.12,   0.08,   0.09,   0.11,   0.09,   0.1,    0.11,
    ])

c = abs(v)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
cmhot = plt.get_cmap("hot")
cax = ax.scatter(x, y, z, v, s=50, c = c, cmap = cmhot)
plt.show()
```

Many thanks in advance to whomever is kind enough to have a look at this for me.

Comment: can you post some example/simplified/fake data that demonstrates the problem? it's hard to run your code otherwise.

Comment: blue isn't even in 'hot'....

Comment: also, what version of mpl/OS are you using and how did you install mpl?

Comment: Per request above, I edited my code to contain my datapoints.

I'm using Windows 7, how do I check my version of MPL? Sorry for all the noobishness.

Comment: `matplotlib.__version__` will give you the version.

Comment: I am 99% sure that question I link to will fix your problem.  I am going to mark this as a duplicate, because it already answered there, but this is a well asked question!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Matplotlib 3D scatter color lost after redraw](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971309/matplotlib-3d-scatter-color-lost-after-redraw)

Comment: also, fix your formatting

Comment: Formatting fixed, thanks for pointing that out. I'm updating my version of pythonxy, and barring that I'm definitely going to follow the question you linked to. Thanks again!

Comment: Lo and behold, it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from pylab import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

th = np.linspace(0, 2 * pi, 100)
x = cos(th)
y = sin(th)
z = th
v = cos(th) * sin(th)
c = abs(v)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
cmhot = plt.get_cmap("hot")
cax = ax.scatter(x, y, z, v, s=50, c = c, cmap = cmhot)
plt.show()
```

Produces [image: example image]

See this [Matplotlib 3D scatter color lost after redraw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971309/matplotlib-3d-scatter-color-lost-after-redraw) that reports the same thing from version 1.1.0 (and has a work-around).  This is a old bug in mpl that has been fixed in later versions (PR [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/762))

Comment: When I run your code above, I get everything in blue. Perhaps I should be reinstalling pythonxy?

And no, no errors at all.