# Plot carpet plot with double X, Y, Z data

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have 3 arrays:

sX: sensor x position (double array)

sY: sensor y position (double array)

sR: sensor radiation measurement (double array)

Using this data I want to  make a 2D plot in python where the x axis is the x coordinate, the y axis is the y coordinate and the colour of the plot is the sensor value.
Since this whould create little colour point, i'd prefer to create something like a carpet plot.

The problem with what I've tryed is that sX and sY have to be column and row indices of the matrix sR(sX, sY).

I understand that the group sX, sY, sR is like a sparse matrix except for the fact that sX and sY are not indices, but real world coordinates.

other solutions like: [Python: 3D scatter losing colormap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18238330/python-3d-scatter-losing-colormap), assume continous Z(X,Y)  functions, but what I have is a discontinious function.

Any help on how to proceed is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using `scatter` , or you can grid you data with a 2D histogram then plot it with `imshow`.